# php array 6 sided Dice Roll Tally issue

Tags: php, arrays, dice

I was hoping someone could figure out why my code is not working for a 6-sided dice tallying the numbers for 6000 rolls using arrays.

```
<?php
//  main    //////////////////////////////////
//$throw_dice = array();
//$tally = array();
echo "debug - code runs to this point<br>\n";

$throw_dice = throw_dice($throw_dice);
$tally = tally_results($throw_dice);
    echo "debug with tally: $tally[4]<br>\n";
    exit;
$line = print_table($tally);
echo $line;


// functions ////////////////////////////////

function throw_dice ($f_throw_dice) {
    /*  required pseudocode:
        for loop from 1 to 6000
            populate each element with random number 1 - 6
        end for loop
        return array
    */
for ($i = 0; $i < 6000; $i++) {
    $f_throw_dice[] = mt_rand(1,6);
}
return array($f_throw_dice);
}

function tally_results ($f_throw_dice) {
    /*  
        use increment system example shown below with associative array:
            $numbers = array(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
            foreach ($numbers as $number) {$tally[$number]++}
            will give 5 for $tally[1] and 4 for $tally[2]
    */
//$tally = array('1' => 1,'2' => 2,'3' => 3,'4' => 4,'5' => 5,'6' => 6,);
//$numbers = array($f_throw_dice);
//$tally[0] = '1';
//$tally[1] = '2';
//$tally[2] = '3';
//$tally[3] = '4';
//$tally[4] = '5';
//$tally[5] = '6';
$tally = array();
foreach ($f_throw_dice as $number) 
    {
        $tally[$number]++;
        echo $tally;

    }
}


function print_table($f_tally) {
    /*  required pseudocode:
        note: concatenate entire formatted printout in one variable $line
        Can start this way:
            $line = "<pre>";
            $line .= sprintf ("DIE #%10s", 'OCCURS');
            $line .= "\n===============\n";
        sort $f_tally by key
        foreach loop 
            concatenate $line with another $f_tally element using the 
                sprintf format from last assignment
        end loop
        return $line
    */
    $line = "<pre>";
    $line .= sprintf ("DIE #%10s", 'OCCURS');
    $line .= "\n===============\n";
    ksort ($f_tally);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($f_tally as $numbers => $tally) {
        echo '<pre>',
        $line .= sprintf('%s        %s', $numbers, $tally), '</pre>';
       // echo '<li>$numbers ($tally)</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

The result should look similar to this:

```
DIE #   OCCURS
==============
1         1000
2          990
3         1038
4         1012
5         1007
6          953
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on info. What problems have you run into?

Comment: What is the result you're getting?

Comment: $tally is an array. `echo $tally` is just going to spit out 6000 copies of the word `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.

**1)** In the `throw_dice` function, change:

```
return array($f_throw_dice);
```

...to:

```
return $f_throw_dice;
```

`$f_throw_dice` is already an array. So by wrapping it in an array function, you're adding an additional layer to your array, which causes the loop in the `tally_results` function to fail. So, just `return` `$f_throw_dice` as is.

**2)** And in the `tally_results` function, change:

```
foreach ($f_throw_dice as $number) 
    {
        $tally[$number]++;
        echo $tally;

    }
```

...to:

```
foreach ($f_throw_dice as $number) 
{
    $tally[$number]++;
}
return $tally;
```

Here you're not returning `$tally` from the function, but rather are `echo`ing it once for every loop over the dice results. Instead, wait 'til the loop is over then `return` it.

**3)** Then, in the `print_table` function, change:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($f_tally as $numbers => $tally) {
    echo '<pre>',
    $line .= sprintf('%s        %s', $numbers, $tally), '</pre>';
   // echo '<li>$numbers ($tally)</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

...to:

```
$line .=  '<ul>';
foreach ($f_tally as $numbers => $tally) {
    $line .=  '<pre>';
    $line .= sprintf('%s        %s', $numbers, $tally) .  '</pre>';
   // echo '<li>$numbers ($tally)</li>';
}
$line .=  '</ul>';
return $line;
```

And here you start building but then switch to `echo`ing, and, again, you don't return anything from this function. So, instead of `echo`ing the results, keep capturing them in the `$line` variable, then echo it at the end of the function.

Comment: #2 will cause a `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset`. Could be prevented with `$tally[$number] =(isset($tally[$number])?$tally[$number]++:1;`

Comment: @Sean thanks for the heads up on the Notice, however what you provided does not work. I think what you mean is: `$tally[$number] = (isset($tally[$number]))? $tally[$number] + 1: 1`

Comment: @bloddyKnuckles - you are correct.